# how to export a node with all the fields into csv in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I would like to know is there any module for exporting all the content cck fields into csv in drupal..

Please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally have had great success with the [feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds). It provides many features that make routine import / exports much easier.

Another way that has worked well for me is the [Views data export module.](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export). It allows you to export any view as a variety of formats.

Answer (score 2):

[Node export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) module may also help you.

> ...the Node export package comes with the CSV - RFC4180 compliant CSV
>   code format. Ideal for viewing in Windows software, and editing data
>   as spreadsheets.